# Covert Ruby hash to array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parse-platform

Convert Ruby Hash to following hash format which uses in **parse.com**:

```
[{
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Tag",
    "objectId": "DLAPiFlMYL"
}, {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Tag",
    "objectId": "trIItAa4bJ"
}]
```

---

Input:

```
{: __type = > "Pointer",
    : className = > "Tag",
    : objectId = > "DLAPiFlMYL"
}
```

---

Output:

```
[{
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Tag",
    "objectId": "DLAPiFlMYL"
}]
```

Comment: Where is the code you wrote to try to solve this?

Comment: to_json gives "{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Tag\",\"objectId\":\"DLAPiFlMYL\"}" , But need [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Tag","objectId":"DLAPiFlMYL"}]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `to_json` method provided by rails

```
{:__type=>"Pointer",:className=>"Tag",:objectId=>"DLAPiFlMYL"}.to_json
```

Comment: it creates "{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Tag\",\"objectId\":\"DLAPiFlMYL\"}" But need [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Tag","objectId":"DLAPiFlMYL"}]

Comment: You need a `JSON` response or a simple `Hash` in a array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://codecraft.io/2011/03/01/ruby-hash-keys-strings-to-symbols/).

```
require 'active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access'
my_hash = {:__type=>"Pointer",:className=>"Tag",:objectId=>"DLAPiFlMYL"}
my_hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new my_hash
=> {"__type"=>"Pointer", "className"=>"Tag", "objectId"=>"DLAPiFlMYL"}
> my_hash['className']
=> "Tag"
> my_hash[:className]
=> "Tag"
```